# How to delete rows that share the same value of a column feature to make one row which keeps all the values of another feature of the deleted rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, data-cleaning

I have a [set of real estate ad data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XUjqeXVgjZJ8jVNAn9MeIb9zHLhVj4mwRs-hk1P050o/edit?usp=sharing). Several of the lines are about the same real estate, so it's full of duplicates that aren't exactly the same. It looks like this :

```
    ID  URL CRAWL_SOURCE    PROPERTY_TYPE   NEW_BUILD   DESCRIPTION IMAGES  SURFACE LAND_SURFACE    BALCONY_SURFACE ... DEALER_NAME DEALER_TYPE CITY_ID CITY    ZIP_CODE    DEPT_CODE   PUBLICATION_START_DATE  PUBLICATION_END_DATE    LAST_CRAWL_DATE LAST_PRICE_DECREASE_DATE
0   22c05930-0eb5-11e7-b53d-bbead8ba43fe    http://www.avendrealouer.fr/location/levallois...   A_VENDRE_A_LOUER    APARTMENT   False   Au rez de chaussÃ©e d'un bel immeuble rÃ©cent,...   ["https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_87...   72.0    NaN NaN ... Lamirand Et Associes    AGENCY  54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2017-03-22T04:07:56.095 NaN 2017-04-21T18:52:35.733 NaN
1   8d092fa0-bb99-11e8-a7c9-852783b5a69d    https://www.bienici.com/annonce/ag440414-16547...   BIEN_ICI    APARTMENT   False   Je vous propose un appartement dans la rue Col...   ["http://photos.ubiflow.net/440414/165474561/p...   48.0    NaN NaN ... Proprietes Privees  MANDATARY   54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2018-09-18T11:04:44.461 NaN 2019-06-06T10:08:10.89  2018-09-25
```

I want to deleter rows that are too similar not to be duplicates and keep only one which keeps and gathers the `CRAWL_SOURCE` of the deleted rows. For instance, let's say I want to keep one row by `CRAWL_SOURCE` if the description or most of the images are alike. So far I only found a way to create a new column to say when descriptions are the same:

```
df['is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated(['DESCRIPTION'])
```

Or when images are the same:

```
def image_similarity(imageAurls,imageBurls):
    imageAurls = ast.literal_eval(imageAurls)
    imageBurls = ast.literal_eval(imageBurls)
    for urlA in imageAurls:
        responseA = requests.get(urlA)
        imgA = Image.open(BytesIO(responseA.content))
        print(imgA)
        for urlB in imageBurls:
            responseB = requests.get(urlB)
            imgB = Image.open(BytesIO(responseB.content))    
            hash0 = imagehash.average_hash(imgA) 
            hash1 = imagehash.average_hash(imgB) 
            cutoff = 5

            if hash0 - hash1 < cutoff:
                print(urlA)
                print(urlB)
                return('similar')
        return('not similar')

df['NextImage'] = df['IMAGES'][df['IMAGES'].index - 1]
df['IsSimilar'] = df.apply(lambda x: image_similarity(x['IMAGES'], x['NextImage']), axis=1)
```

Therefore, how to delete rows that share the same description, or which share the same photos, and make one which gathers the `CRAWL_SOURCE` of the deleted rows ?

Generally speaking : **How to delete rows that share the same value of a column feature to make one row which gather all the values of another column feature?**

Nota : if you have any other ideas to discover the houses that might be the same as well, I will be happy to hear them. I think two rows might be talking about the same real estate if the following features are alike :

```
SURFACE LAND_SURFACE    BALCONY_SURFACE TERRACE_SURFACE ROOM_COUNT  BEDROOM_COUNT   BATHROOM_COUNT  LUNCHROOM_COUNT TOILET_COUNT    FURNISHED   FIREPLACE   AIR_CONDITIONING    GARDEN  SWIMMING_POOL   BALCONY TERRACE CELLAR  PARKING PARKING_COUNT   HEATING_TYPES   HEATING_MODE    FLOOR   FLOOR_COUNT CONSTRUCTION_YEAR   ELEVATOR    CARETAKER   ENERGY_CONSUMPTION  GREENHOUSE_GAS_CONSUMPTION  MARKETING_TYPE  PRICE   PRICE_M2
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Record Linkage method and it has been done already.
I suggest you a library that detects similarities using words distances calculations and with a decent documentation: Python Record Linkage Toolkit.

Once you import the library, you must index the sources you intend to compare, something like this:

```
indexer = recordlinkage.Index()

#using url as intersection
indexer.block('url')
candidate_links = indexer.index(df_a, df_b)

c = recordlinkage.Compare()
```

Let's say you want to compare based on the similiraties of strings, but they don't match exactly:

```
c.string('descriptionA', 'descriptionB', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.85)
```

And if you want an exact match you should use:

```
c.exact('imageUrl')
```

Anyway, there are more resources(libraries) based on Record Linkage.